# Calling wp_signon doesn't log the user in

Tags: login, authentication

I'm currently programming a single sign-on mechanism for my Wordpress site to allow my company's helpdesk system to authenticate against Wordpress.

In order to allow this to happen I'm making use of wp_signon() to sign the user in if they aren't already signed in. Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require("wp-blog-header.php");

if(!is_user_logged_in() && $_POST["log"] == "") {
    //redirect to login form that submits to this PHP script
    exit(0);
}

if(!is_user_logged_in() && $_POST["log"] != "") {
    $creds = array('user_login' => $_POST["log"], 'user_password' => $_POST['pwd'], 'remember' => $_POST["rememberme"]);
    $user_info = wp_signon($creds, false);

    if(!is_a($user_info, 'WP_Error')) {
        $username = $_POST["log"];
        wp_set_current_user($user->ID, $username);
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, true, false); 
        do_action('wp_login', $username);
    } else {
        write_log(ERROR, "Error authenticating: " . $user_info->get_error_message($user_info->get_error_code()));
    }

$user_info = wp_get_current_user();

/* Code from here uses user attributes to generate and encrypt a single sign-on token */
?>
```

The problem I'm facing is that even after calling `wp_signon()`, `wp_set_current_user()`, `wp_set_auth_cookie()` and the login actions, the user still isn't logged in. I get their $user_info object, but they aren't logged into Wordpress, so later on when they follow a secured link back from the support system they can't get to the page and have to log in again (thus defeating the purpose of single sign-on).

In addition, I've tried replacing the whole `wp_signon()` section with `auth_redirect()` and that does successfully log the user into the site, but I'm finding they get redirected to the profile page, even though the URL has a query parameter to redirect them back to my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that your code is executed before `auth_redirect()` is called.

In simple words, you need to hook the whole function using `setup_theme` action. It worked in my case.